# Finding the highest match between a reference on and a set of images

Tags: image, ros, feature-extraction

I have a reference image and a number of images that I want to find out which of these images has the highest match with the reference one. I am working with ROS kinetic 16.4. Now, what is the best method for this aim? what is the procedure?

the image is about sleepers of the railway track. In a specific location, with the stereo camera which is attached to the body of the robot, a number of images from the sleepers are taken. Later, I will use one of these images as a reference, then I will move the robot 1m forward and backward while simultaneously capturing a number of images and comparing with the reference one. Now which type of technique or method should i use to be able to find an image that has the highest match with the reference one.
Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough info to really answer the question. You could try something like template matching with opencv. What have you tried so far?

Comment: the image is about sleepers of the railway track. In a specific location, with a stereo camera which is attached to the body of the robot, a number of images from the sleepers are taken. Later, I will use one of these images as a reference, then I moved the robot 1m forward and backward and captures a number of images. Now among these images I want to find image that has the highest match wit the reference one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would you please share the SIFT package link in GitHub? I also want to use SIFT for finding the highest match between a reference image and the images capture by the stereo camera online. I want to have this matching done online, and upon finding the highest match, the robot stop.

I am working with ROS kinetic 16.04, and python 2.7 Thanks a lot